# Usb only shows up at 'safely remove hardware'

Tags: usb, windows-to-go

I've got a Kingston Datatraveler Workspace 32gb that has 'windows to go' on it. After installing some updates and rebooting, I could not get past the bios screen. When I boot from my HD and just plug in the usb, the usb drive does not appear under explorer, neither under disk management. 
The only place where the usb stick shows up is under the 'safely remove hardware' icon on the taskbar. 
Is there anything I could try or check before I declare it broke?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a data recovery program such as [Easeus Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/datarecovery/) or [x-ways](http://www.x-ways.net/). If those programs do not see the device, try booting to a live Linux distro such as Ubuntu, Slitaz, Knoppix. One of those should be good for your machine. If you can see the device there, backup your data and reformat the device.